# How can I add the same prefix to all instances of a list of words in Notepad++?

Tags: text, notepad++, prefixes

I have a large block of text, containing one or more instances of each of a list of words. I need to add a prefix to all instances of each word on the list.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do -

List of words:

```
foo
bar
```

Prefix:

```
xyz
```

Text before:

```
onklnagknaubosabdof foo dklfn fknk foo klnksdnia bar dsknska foo knkn bar
```

Text after:

```
onklnagknaubosabdof xyzfoo dklfn fknk xyzfoo klnksdnia xyzbar dsknska xyzfoo knkn xyzbar
```

How can I do this in Notepad++? Or is there another tool that can do this for me easily?

Comment: What must be the result for `blah foobar blah`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?=\b(?:foo|bar)\b)`
- Replace with: `xyz`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?=         # start lookahead, make sure we have after:
  \b        # word boundary, to NOT match xyzfoo or foobar
  (?:       # start non capture group
    foo     # literally
   |        # OR
    bar     # literally
  )         # end group
  \b        # word boundary, to NOT match xyzfoo or foobar
)           #end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
onklnagknaubosabdof xyzfoo dklfn fknk xyzfoo klnksdnia xyzbar dsknska xyzfoo knkn xyzbar
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

If you want to replace `foobar` with `xyzfooxyzbar`, remove the word boundaries:

- Find what: `(?=(?:foo|bar))`

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation of the regular expression! This is particularly helpful for me, since I'm not that familiar with regular expression syntax.